# Resolution failed exception was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, .net

I face the below given exception, whenever I try to save a record into the database using the manager and repository parts of other module. This exception raises in the controller. I'm a newbie and does not have any knowledge about this. Kindly help me.

Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "XV.XS.Framework.ExceptionHandling.IExceptionHandler", name = "(none)".
Exception occurred while: while resolving.

### Exception is: ActivationException - Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type ExceptionManager, key ""

At the time of the exception, the container was:

Resolving XV.XS.Framework.ExceptionHandling.IExceptionHandler,(none)

The inner exceptions are:
1) {"Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type ExceptionManager, key \"\""}

2)  {"Resolution of the dependency failed, type = \"Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionManager\", name = \"(none)\".\r\nException occurred while: while resolving.\r\nException is: InvalidOperationException - The type ExceptionManager cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value.\r\n-----------------------------------------------\r\nAt the time of the exception, the container was:\r\n\r\n  Resolving Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionManager,(none)\r\n"}

3) {"The type ExceptionManager cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value."}

Comment: I guess you are missing an assembly. Do a search for IExceptionHandler in the solution and reference the project that contains the found class.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in a project I inherited.
It turned out it was looking for a connection string that I had changed the name of :D